# Wild card routing in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am creating a website having different users , each user can register the web site and post their data to the website like a blogging site.

using the username of each user how can i fetch their own page publicly.

ie ; my domain name is ***www.example.com*** then

how can i use ***www.firstuser.example.com*** to fetch that individual data.

what i tried is on route.php is given below

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working copy of your code:

```php
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        return User::whereId($id)
                   ->where('account', $account)
                   ->firstOrFail();
    });
});
```

You can also use **[Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding)** to load the proper user and return it directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response ...
how can i redirect to a controller when i got a wildcard sub domain. ?
ie ; if the subdomain is ***www.abc.example.com*** then i need to check the validity of the subdomain in the user table , if subdomain exists fetch all post under that particular user and present his own view    ??

Comment: You don't need to have multiple controllers for each subdomain. You need to express your needs clearly and even try and post some test code. What you are currently asking is very vague.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dov Benyomin Sohacheski
i am currently having only one controller for this purpose, my question is my subdomain is changing dynamically , i need to fetch data regarding each subdomain name.

<?php

// app/routes.php

Route::group(array('domain' => '{dynamic}.example.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function($dynamic, $page) {
        // here i need to pass dynamic domain name to a controller fn
    });
});